# Use x-webkit-speech with a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, usability, speech-recognition

I have a field in my webapp where users are entering a large amount of text.  I would like to implement the x-webkit-speech element.  it works in all the

```
<input>
```

boxes, but I cannot get it to render in the

```
<textarea name="uxMyInput" rows="30" cols="20" id="uxMyInput" onblur="convert();" style="width:100%;" x-webkit-speech=""></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it only works on inputs. I assume that support for longer text entry will come eventually, but as users might expect to record much longer entries I suspect they were worried the accuracy and time for processing would be affected.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid that was the issue, but nice to hear it confirmed.

Comment: Hopefully it will work with text area soon. Not being able to wrap the input box is very limiting.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is fairly straightforward: add a text input box above your text area and then use the onwebkitspeechchange attribute to cause the newly recognized text to be copied from the input box to the text area.

I have posted a code sample on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/theo/GZ5mL/